# Grouping Nodes by first letter of field

Tags: views

I've around 300 pages in wiki style (word -> explanation).

I need to create an overview page with all words categorized by first letter of page title/custom field (so basically [0-9] or a, b, c etc).

I would like to know you there are any already some good solution to do that?
Also considering in best way to go :)

I need something like this (actually in 3 columns)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: There is a views sample doing something similar called 'Glossary'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with solution from @Colin Shipton + `column-count` CSS property. That solutions works in all browsers except IE9 and less.

Answer (score 10):

Add the field a second time so it appears twice in Fields, check exclude from display and uncheck link this field to the original piece of content. Under rewrite results check trim this field to a maximum length, and enter 1 in the textfield.

Under format click settings next to unformatted list, etc. and select the right field in the grouping options.

You'll probably need to adjust the sort criteria too

Comment: Answer is still working with Drupal 8, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please Refer this, it may help you out.

 https://www.drupal.org/node/1078962.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a *view* of that content type
- Remove *published date sort criteria* and add the field you need as sort criteria in *ascending order* . It appears as `Content: Title (asc)` in sort criteria

Comment: OK, but I need to group result by first letter of custom field. Please look on my screenshot in main post

Answer (score 0):

Sir,

Click "theme information" then look at the name of the file that applies to the node reference field.

Create a .tpl.php file with a candidate name that's specific enough for your needs will be something like views-view--viewname--fieldname.tpl.php.

Click the link for the template file in use in theme information for this field, and views will show you the code in that file. Copy & paste that code to your new file.

In the new file, you'll want to write a little PHP to output your links as a list. If you enable the devel module, put in the page, and inspect what's available. One of them will be an array of links. Output that.

Thank You.